# implication of the Abel–Ruffini theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, radicals

I am taking a course in abstract algebra, and we proved the following theorem:
[image]

I want to prove something more specific. Let's look at polynomials of degree 5 over C.
Someone is claiming he has a magic formula, which receives the coefficients of a polynomial of degree 5, and returns its roots using only basic operations and radicals.
I want to understand, how I can prove this person wrong using the theorem above.
In this case, the theorem talks about the field of rational functions with 5 variables over C. It shows that I can't express $t_1, ..., t_5$ (the roots of f) in terms of $s_1,...,s_5$, in this abstract field.
I understand the proof in this context, but I want to understand how I can use it concretely in order to prove this person wrong.
In the sources that I have seen, they say that Abel–Ruffini theorem implies what I want to prove, but they don't show how. Can someone help me understand how you can show this?
I am adding the proof we saw in the course:

[image]

Comment: It seems clear: the corollary you quote asserts there exists a general formula if and only if the degree is no more than $4$.

Comment: @Bernard I am trying to understand how the formal corollary, which talks about the field of rational functions with d variables over C, implies that there is no formula for polynomials over C

Comment: I see – I misunderstood what you were asking. I think it's a matter of Galois group (there exist quintic equations which are solvable by radicals, and there is a Maple module which solves them when they are. If I remember well, it's a matter of the Galois group of the polynomial being metacyclic).

Comment: Switch to Galois.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question. I was annoyed by the same thing after learning Galois theory. Before learning it I thought that I will see a proof that there is no formula which works specifically for polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$, but instead of that I only saw a proof that there is no formula which works for polynomials over the field $\mathbb{C}(t_1,...,t_n)$, which is a **much** bigger field. I was very disappointed for a while, but lucky for me I managed to think of a proof myself.

Suppose there is a formula which works for polynomials of degree $n\geq 5$ over $\mathbb{C}$. The formula contains the field operations, taking roots, the coefficients of a polynomial and some complex constants. (for example the quadratic formula $\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ uses the constants $2,4,...$). The main thing we should note is that the formula can contain only **finitely many** constants. Let's call them $z_1,...,z_k$. So our formula is actually a formula over the field $K:=\mathbb{Q}(z_1,...,z_k)$. Note that this field is countable, since it is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable there must be an element $t_1\in\mathbb{C}$ which is transcendental over $K$. Again, $K(t_1)$ is countable, so there is $t_2\in\mathbb{C}$ which is transcendental over $K(t_1)$. We continue this way, and finally get a field $K(t_1,...,t_n)$ where $t_i$ is transcendental over $K(t_1,...,t_{i-1})$ for all $i$. Now define the polynomial $f=(x-t_1)...(x-t_n)$ and call its symmetric functions $s_1,...,s_n$. (the coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$). Finally, let $L=K(s_1,..,s_n)$, this is a subfield of $K(t_1,...,t_n)$.

Now, what can we say about $L$? I claim that every polynomial of degree $n$ in $L[x]$ is solvable by radicals. Why? Well, take a polynomial $g\in L[x]$ of degree $n$ and put its coefficients in the formula we have. The coefficients of $g$ are obviously in $L$, and remember that the **constants** in the formula belong to $K\subseteq L$, so they are in $L$ as well! So this shows $g$ is solvable by radicals over $L$.

But now let's go back to the polynomial $f=(x-t_1)(x-t_2)...(x-t_n)\in L[x]$. As we showed above it must be solvable by radicals over $L$, so its Galois group over $L$ is solvable. On the other hand, using the fact that $t_1,...,t_n$ are algebraically independent over $K$ (which means $t_i$ is transcendental over $K(t_1,...,t_{i-1})$ for all $i$) we can conclude that $Gal(K(t_1,...,t_n)/K(s_1,...,s_n))\cong S_n$, this is exactly the same proof as the proof that the Galois group of the general polynomial in the field of rational functions is $S_n$. This means the Galois group of $f$ over $L$ is $S_n$, a contradiction.

The difference is that in my proof $t_1,...,t_n$ are all complex numbers, and not just formal variables like in the field of rational functions. So here $f=(x-t_1)...(x-t_n)$ is a **specific polynomial** over $\mathbb{C}$ for which the formula we took fails.

Comment: hey, thank you for the answer. I think you need to define the polynomial as $f\left(t\right)=t^{n}-t_{1}\cdot t^{n-1}+...+\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot t_{n}$ , since you don't want the roots to be in the field, just the  coefficients

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I already edited my answer. The important field is indeed $L=K(s_1,...,s_n)$. The field $K(t_1,...,t_n)$ is the splitting field.

Comment: maybe it's just not updating for me, but I think there are still places you need to switch between s and t. Either way, I understood what you meant, thank you

Comment: I think as it is written now it is fine. The roots $t_1,...,t_n$ are algebraically independent, and this can be used to prove that $Gal(K(t_1,...,t_n)/K(s_1,...,s_n))\cong S_n$. The algebraic independence implies that any permutation of the roots can be extended to an automorphism.

Comment: we actually get that the field K is algebraically closed and therefore contains the algebraic closure of Q. If we show that the algebraic closure of Q can't be generated by a finite amount of elements (which is a bit tricky because the elements here aren't necessarily algebraic) we can get an alternative proof

Comment: Why is it algebraically closed? Assuming our formula is true we can conclude that every polynomial in $K[x]$ splits in some radical extension of $K$, but not necessary in $K$ itself. (remember that the formula might also contain the operation of taking roots)

Comment: right, my mistake